# nested query with combining strings

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join

I'm trying to write a nested query that also includes combining strings together (a variable 2-letter string & a fixed 6-letter string '-EXTRA').

Person

| Name | Department |
| --- | --- |
| Tim | AA |
| Fred | BB |

Stock

| Part | Store | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | AA | 3 |
| Item2 | AA-EXTRA | 6 |
| Item1 | BB | 2 |
| Item2 | BB-EXTRA | 1 |

I want to write a query that sees who is using the system now and returns the stock of parts that are affiliated with their department. For example, if Fred is currently logged in, he should see only:

| Part | Store | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | BB | 2 |
| Item2 | BB-EXTRA | 1 |

These are my tries so far. (USER sees who is logged in currently. This isn't the issue, it has worked for other queries.)

```
SELECT *
FROM Stock
WHERE Store IN CONCAT(( SELECT Department FROM Person WHERE Name = USER ), '-EXTRA')
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Stock
WHERE Store IN ( SELECT Department FROM Person WHERE Name = USER );
```

```
SELECT *
FROM Stock
WHERE Store LIKE "( SELECT Department FROM Person WHERE Name = USER )%";
```

Neither worked.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @GMB, but your codes didn't work initially. This problem was difficult to solve because my *Person* table had records where the column *Name* repeats, but the column *Department* is different. ie A person can be in 2 different departments.

As such, the nested query `SELECT Department FROM Person WHERE Name = USER` sometimes resulted in a table of the User's 2 different Departments.

The `CONCACT` or `LIKE "***%&"` functions don't work on tables, and it caused my codes to fail.

Months ago, I overcame it with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Stock
WHERE
STORE IN (SELECT DEPARTMENT FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = USER)
OR
STORE IN (SELECT DEPARTMENT||'-EXTRA' FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = :USER)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a join and an `in` predicate:

```
select s.*
from stock s
inner join person p on s.store in (p.department, concat(p.department, '-EXTRA'))
where p.name = 'Fred'
```

This allows a user to see a stock if the store name matches that of their department (with possible string prefix `'-EXTRA'`).

`exists` also comes to mind:

```
select s.*
from stock s
where exists (
    select 1 
    from person p
    where p.name = 'Fred' 
        and s.store in (p.department, concat(p.department, '-EXTRA')
)
```